# When on iPhone 5 landscape mode, the button on the right of navigation bar stops working, how to fix it?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

When updating my old program for iPhone 5's 4 inch screen, I found that the navigation controller keeps to its original 3.5 inch screen size and refuse to stretch to fit the 4 inch screen even when its view controller's view and tableview controller's view are all stretch to fit the 4 inch screen. Because the navigation controller's view is not visible during normal use, people may miss it. Because it refuses to fit the new 4 inch screen, when in landscape mode, the screen go beyond the navigation controller's view width and the right button fall off the boundary and becomes unresponsive. In order to show the situation above, I set the navigation controller's view's background color to semi-transparent red and the table view's background color to semi-transparent blue. as shown in the screen shoots below. The question is, how to fix the problem. the plus button are not responsive when in landscape mode, but in portrait mode, it works fine.

[image: http://zhuyali.homedns.org:900/images/screenshot1.jpg]
[image: http://zhuyali.homedns.org:900/images/screenshot2.jpg]

Comment: how is the navigation controller added to the view hierarchy?  it should resize on its own just fine.  (make a new project using the master/detail template and prove it to yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

Either your navigation controller’s view or, more likely, the window that contains it, are not getting set up with the correct frame. If you’re creating the window in code, make sure you’re using UIScreen `-applicationFrame` or `-bounds` rather than a hardcoded `(320, 460)` or `(320, 480)`; if you’re using a NIB, check your autoresizing masks and layout settings.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I went to MainWindows.xib and checked its attributes inspector and changed the size from none to Freeform which handles both 3.5 inch and 4.0 inch screen very well. See the screen shots below: http://zhuyali.homedns.org:900/images/screenshot3.jpg

Comment: Actually, when compiling, got 2 warnings. I should keep the about settings to none and change Windows checkbox for Full Screen at Launch, see screenshot below: http://zhuyali.homedns.org:900/images/screenshot4.jpg